# How to process stdin line by line in ReasonML?

Tags: stdin, reason

I would like to write a simple program in ReasonML that takes data from stdin and process it line by line.

As of November 2018, this doesn't seem to be covered in the "Language Basics" or the "FAQ" sections of the [official documentation](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/what-and-why), and it is difficult to understand how to do it from the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on examples found in the [OCaml documentation](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/streams.html), it seems one can do that using the following tools:

- `input_line` and `stdin` from the [`Pervasives`](https://reasonml.github.io/api/Pervasives.html) automatically loaded module.
- Dealing with the `End_of_file` [exception](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/exception) (raised by `input_line` when nothing more comes from `stdin`) to wrap lines in the [`option`](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/null-undefined-option) type.
- The [`Stream`](https://reasonml.github.io/api/Stream.html) module to generate a stream of lines and process them.

Here, we just print back the lines:

```
/* Function ignoring the "stream count" argument
(whatever that means) and wrapping lines in option.
*/
let get_one_line = (_: int): option(string) => {
    /* Wrap a line in option, or handle exception
    to return None when stdin is exhausted */
    try (Some(input_line(stdin))) {
        | End_of_file => None
    };
};

/* Create a stream of lines from the above function */
let lines = Stream.from(get_one_line);

/* Process the lines from the above stream */
Stream.iter(print_endline, lines);
```

---

Another approach that works when compiling in native using [`dune`](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html) is to install the OCaml package [Batteries included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) (`opam install batteries`) and adding `(libraries batteries)` in the `dune` configuration file to get access to useful predefined functions such as `BatIO.lines_of` or `BatEnum.iter`.

Reading and printing back lines from stdin can then be done with very little code:

```
let lines = BatIO.lines_of(BatIO.stdin);
BatEnum.iter(print_endline, lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to reasonml like yourself and wanted to do this as easily as possible. Reading ocaml isn't something I'm good with yet. Using `in_channel` didn't work at all either.

Here is what I did, read the lines in node then convert to a ReasonML List. Perhaps it will help other newcomers.

```
let convert: string => int = [%raw a => "{return +a}"];

let input: list(int) =
  Node.Fs.readFileAsUtf8Sync("input.txt")
  |> Js.String.split("\n")
  |> Array.map(convert)  /* js side conversion, might not be needed if keeping as string */
  |> Array.to_list;

Js.log(input);
```

Read more about `external`here https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/intro-to-external